# Fetch CORS request fail in Service Worker

Tags: cors, service-worker

I am doing some development about Service Worker. Our propose is very simple, just log every request from our app.js. I am following the guide from Google website. I just need a listener for 'fetch' event.

My app and API are in the different hosts.

My Service Worker code is like:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  console.log(event.request);
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    const response = await fetch(event.requet);
    // we will do something here.
    return response;
  }());
});
```

My app.js is very simple now:

```
  const url = 'https://api.github.com/users/CrisLi'
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

This version code works well until I change the request URL to another server (not GitHub one).

```
  const url = 'https://172.16.50.91:8080/BNfSZIiGMs37unHZXtnSFv5?access_token=WUMzMgAAAV63ciKxAACowFVEVXNvNEhudXVzS3FidXBsNTVSeGE1IAAAAANUODNfd0VWcXBMVTJsSWVWakJVWTBNNVpqbGlPR1V5Wmpr'
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

This new server URL supports CORS already. But the if I do fetch request in the Service Worker code, the error happened.

```
The FetchEvent for "https://172.16.50.91:8080/BNfSZIiGMs37unHZXtnSFv5?access_token=WUMzMgAAAV63ciKxAACowFVEVXNvNEhudXVzS3FidXBsNTVSeGE1IAAAAANUODNfd0VWcXBMVTJsSWVWakJVWTBNNVpqbGlPR1V5Wmpr" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.
Promise rejected (async)
self.addEventListener @ service-worker.js:62
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
(index):25 GET https://172.16.50.91:8080/BNfSZIiGMs37unHZXtnSFv5?access_token=WUMzMgAAAV63ciKxAACowFVEVXNvNEhudXVzS3FidXBsNTVSeGE1IAAAAANUODNfd0VWcXBMVTJsSWVWakJVWTBNNVpqbGlPR1V5Wmpr net::ERR_FAILED
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

**If I remove the Service Worker code, call fetch API directly, it works fine.** I can fetch the result to my server. The only difference between 2 versions code is the server. I think it has something to do with CORS. The Github API handle CORS very well, but we don't.

How to use fetch API in the Service Worker to make it work like in the normal javascript?

**I don't understand why the code in the javascript thread works fine, but can't work in the Service Worker.**

I try to change the default fetch request mode to 'no-cors', it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Find result. My server is a self-signed https server. Service Worker can't CORS access to the self-signed https server.

Comment: Is there no way to do CORS for self-signed https server?